# Ubuntu 14.04 Update Fail Error

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, sudo

So I'm having an issue with trying to run "sudo apt-get update". After running the command, I get the error

```
Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release     
Unable to find expected entry 'maindeb/source/Sources' in Release file    
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Any ideas or help? I've searched for this error on Google and the likes, with no prevail for my particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open terminal and type:

> `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

and look for a malformed line that with the word "maindeb". Delete "deb" and keep only "main"

eg: if the line reads:

> deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty maindeb

change it to:

> deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

Save and close.

Comment: Ok, so I went through and did as you have instructed, however, now I get this error when trying update command: "W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'http://repository.spotify.com/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)"

Comment: remove the lines with spotify or disable the extras repositories by going to other-software tabs in software&updates and un-cheking canonical partners.

Comment: after opening in nano, this is the only line that has "maindeb":        "deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty maindeb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"        I remove the deb from maindeb and then the update error shifts from 'maindeb/source/Sources' to 'repository.spotify.com/source/Sources'.      I assume thats because it's all in the same line?

Comment: will removing the lines with Spotify cause issues when using said program? Canonical partners is already unchecked.

Comment: You can remove the `deb-src extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main repository.spotify.com stable non-free`. That should not cause any problems. See [this](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-Windows/wrong-repositories/td-p/42751) link for reference

Comment: Ok, so I went into nano, and from the line, "deb-src extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty maindeb repository.spotify.com stable non-free" I removed, '...deb repository.spotify.com stable non-free',  reran update and updated successfully. Should I go ahead and remove the rest of this line, or should I stop now that it worked?

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the updating server. You can do this by going to: Software Sources > Install from > Other > Select best server the. Re run the update command.

Comment: ok, so I went through and changed the server to the best server option, it scanned and I chose the server that it highlighted.. reran update and got:       W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'maindeb/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)       Am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: @PJxSlain  one of the other servers then.

Comment: So I changed the server again, and when it attempted to update the repo info, I get the error: "W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'maindeb/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. "  I still get the same error when I run the update command as well.

Comment: I suspect a typo in your sources.lst file. See my answer above.

Comment: How do I go about fixing this sources.lst file typo then?